# Orchard 1.6 CMS. redirect from service to one view

Tags: orchardcms

is there any possible way to redirect from sercive...
this is a idserver integration so..

i have to redirect from RolesBasedAuthorizationService.cs to one warning page (anonymous.cshtml)
if that user have no roles like a anonymous user...

Answer (score 1):

`HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect` should work from pretty much anywhere. Not the most testable code, but it'll do what you want.

Comment: Thanks for yr reply.. when i am tried i am getting error "cannot redirect after HTTP headers have been sent." send me taht line...                                UrlHelper urlHelper = new UrlHelper(_httpContext.Current().Request.RequestContext);
                        _httpContext.Current().Response.Redirect(urlHelper.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request.ApplicationPath + "/admin/Anonymous");

Comment: Where are you calling it from?

Comment: In RolesBasedAuthorizationService.cs /* Orchard.Roles.service */

Comment: Why are you modifying a core module class?

Comment: i am new to orchard this is my first task. so i have been learning through googling only. give solution me...

Comment: This is way too complicated for a first task with Orchard. I recommend you start with something a lot simpler and work your way to more complex tasks progressively.
Changing authentication should be done through a module. Look at existing modules that do similar things (such as oAuth).